# Compare the elements from a list with another list through list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to compare the elements from a list with another list, taking into account the position of each element
For instance... I have a list called one, with some values

`one = ['o', 'n', 'e']`

than I have another list `['o', 'w', 'e']`
Therefore it should print as a result `[True, False, True]`

On the other hand a list such as `['t', 'o', 'o']` should return `[False, False, False]` as none of its elements correspond to the current value from the list one

What I have till now is the following code which is not returning what I need, as it is returning `[False, True, True]`

```
[x in [y for y in one] for x in number]
```

By the way, I would like to make this with list comprehension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is standard for processing iterables in parallel:

```
>>> one = ['o', 'n', 'e']
>>> two = ['o', 'w', 'e']
>>> [i == j for i, j in zip(one, two)]
[True, False, True]
```

or

```
>>> two = ['t', 'o', 'o']
>>> [i == j for i, j in zip(one, two)]
[False, False, False]
```